# submitfeed error in amazon mws api - attribute does not match the list of valid values

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am tearing my hair out trying to work out why my child variation test product will not get accepted by the amazon mws api using the submitfeed operation. I have checked the xsd files over and over again but i still get the following error message

```
            <Result>
            <MessageID>1</MessageID>
            <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
            <ResultMessageCode>8105</ResultMessageCode>
            <ResultDescription>The data you provided for an attribute does not match the list of valid values.  Please select a valid value from the Data Definitions and resubmit.</ResultDescription>
            <AdditionalInfo>
                <SKU>TESTSKU-1</SKU>
            </AdditionalInfo>
        </Result>
```

from this submission

```
  <Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OperationType>Update</OperationType>
<Product>
    <SKU>TESTSKU-1</SKU>
    <StandardProductID>
      <Type>ASIN</Type>
      <Value>B011223344</Value>
    </StandardProductID>
    <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
    <ItemPackageQuantity>1</ItemPackageQuantity>
    <NumberOfItems>1</NumberOfItems>
    <DescriptionData>
      <Title><![CDATA[TEST2 Aquarius Star Sign Mens T Shirt - White, 100% Heavy Cotton Mens]]></Title>
      <Brand>StarliteClothing</Brand>
      <Description><![CDATA[TEST2 Aquarius Sign Mens T Shirt, 100% Heavy Cotton Mens & Boys Tee Shirts in All Sizes.  Made with 100% Heavy Cotton either Fruit of the Loom or Gilden T-Shirts.]]></Description>
      <BulletPoint>100% Cotton</BulletPoint>
      <BulletPoint>Everyday Casual Wear</BulletPoint>
      <BulletPoint>Sports Wear</BulletPoint>
      <BulletPoint>100</BulletPoint>
      <ShippingWeight unitOfMeasure="GR">425.0</ShippingWeight>
      <MSRP currency="GBP">9.99</MSRP>
      <Manufacturer></Manufacturer>
      <ItemType>example-item-type</ItemType>
      <RecommendedBrowseNode>116192031</RecommendedBrowseNode>
      <RecommendedBrowseNode>116195031</RecommendedBrowseNode>
    </DescriptionData>
    <ProductData>
      <Clothing>
             <VariationData>
                <Parentage>child</Parentage>
                <Size>Small</Size>
                <Color>White</Color>
                <VariationTheme>SizeColor</VariationTheme>
             </VariationData>
             <ClassificationData>
                <ClothingType>Shirt</ClothingType>
                <Department>Mens</Department>
                <StyleKeywords>Apparel</StyleKeywords>
                <ColorMap>White</ColorMap>
                <InnerMaterial>White</InnerMaterial>
                <OuterMaterial>White</OuterMaterial>
                <Season>All Seasons</Season>
                <CollarType>Crew</CollarType>
                <SleeveType>Short</SleeveType>
                <IsAdultProduct>false</IsAdultProduct>
             </ClassificationData>
      </Clothing>
    </ProductData>
</Product>
```

the error message does not specify which attribute is incorrect. can anyone see which value is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error when my column headings did not match the allowed column headings that Amazon was allowing.  Sometimes the specifications for column headings may change.  Sometimes they drop certain fields in the tables (go figure) so just check all the column headings to match yours.  Check the spelling also, it has to be an exact match. 
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Your XML validates, so the problem cannot be located by looking at the XSD. Whatever the error message's "list of values" is referring to, it surely isn't the XSD. I'm afraid you'll have to call Amazon to find the cause of your problem.

For the sake of completeness: I did have to wrap your XML with the following code to make it valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>X</MerchantIdentifier>
   </Header>
   <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
   <Message>
   ... your code here ...
   </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```